# Kubernetes Helm chart initiation with Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am implementing the continuous integration and continuous deployment by using Ansible, Docker, Jenkins and Kubernetes. I already created one Kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes by using Ansible and kubespray deployment. And I have 30 - 40 number of micro service application. I need to create that much of service and deployments.

**My Confusion**

When I am using Kubernetes package manager Kubernetes Helm chart, then do I need to initiate my chart on master node or in my base machine from where I I deployed my kubernet cluster ?

1. If I am initiating inside master, then can I use kubectl to deploy using ssh on remote worker nodes?
2. If I am initiating outside the Kubernetes cluster nodes , then Can i use kubectl command to deploy in Kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: I think so you need to run the helm charts where helm will be installed. mostly it will be on master. the deployment in k8s is done on the worker nodes using the deployment file. since the worker nodes are configured you don't need to worry on the deployment k8s will take care of that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion seems to lie in the configuration and interactions of Helm components. [This explanation](https://rimusz.net/tillerless-helm/) provides a good graphics to represent the relationships.

If you are using the traditional Helm/Tiller configuration, Helm will be installed locally on your machine and, assuming you have the correct `kubectl` configuration, you can "initialize" your cluster by running `helm init` to install Tiller into your cluster. Tiller will run as a deployment in `kube-system`, and has the RBAC privileges to create/modify/delete/view the chart resources. Helm will automatically manage all the API objects for you, and the kube-scheduler will schedule the pods to all your nodes accordingly. You should not be directly interacting with your master and nodes via your console.

In either configuration, you would always be making the Helm deployment from your local machine with a `kubectl` access to your cluster.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I don't want to install Helm client in my local. I am trying to implement ci/cd pipeline. So this kuberentes helm command need to be triggered from a Jenkins pipeline job when one developer commits to repository. I already installing jenkins in one control  node. This control node is outside of kubernetes cluster. When there is a commit to repo, jenkins job need to trigger this Helm command for kubernetes deployment. So If I am installing Helm in master node where jenkins is installed , then Is possible to deploy in cluster through jenkins pipeline job ?

Comment: Yes this is possible. I am not very familiar with the Jenkins configuration, but you can definitely install Helm in your Jenkins pod image (if possible) and call it directly from your pipeline. Alternatively, you can also use the HelmOperator that @Nepomucen has mentioned. Whatever you do, don't install it directly on your master node machine as your pods should not have access to the master node directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for the way for running helm client inside your Kubernetes cluster, please check the concept of [Helm-Operator](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux/blob/master/site/helm-operator.md).

I would recommend you also to look around for term "[GitOps](https://www.weave.works/technologies/gitops/)" - set of practices which combines Git with Kubernetes, and sets Git as a source of truth for your declarative infrastructure and applications.

There are two great OSS projects out there, that implements GitOps best practices:

- [flux](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux) (uses Helm-Operator)
- [Jenkins-x](https://jenkins-x.io/demos/) (uses helm as a part of release pipeline, check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHe7R_iZSLU&t=1552s) session on YT to see it in action)